# sendTransaction results in double send with arbitrary library call

Tags: truffle

I have a situation I have isolated that seems very bizarre to me and I cannot figure out. I am running truffle v1.0.2 (not latest) and testrpc v2.0.5.

When I send ETH from an account to a contract with a fallback function that calls a library function, the sending account is **reduced by twice as much as the send value**. When I remove the library call, it sends the expected amount. It should all be clear from the below code. What's going on?

You can clone and test it for yourself at: https://github.com/raineorshine/double-send.

Contract.sol:

```
import "MyLib.sol";

contract Contract {
  function() {
    // The test is showing that the balance of account[1] is decremented 
    // by 200 instead of the expected 100.
    // If I remove this line, the balance of account[1] is decremented 
    // by 100.
    MyLib.doNothing();
  }
}
```

MyLib.sol:

```
library MyLib {
  function doNothing() {
  }
}
```

test/spec.js:

```
describe('test', () => {
  contract('Contract', () => {
    it('send to deployed address', () => {
      const contract = Contract.deployed()
      const initialBalance = web3.eth.getBalance(web3.eth.accounts[1])
      console.log(web3.fromWei(initialBalance).toString())
      web3.eth.sendTransaction({ from: web3.eth.accounts[1], to: contract.address, value: web3.toWei(100) })

      const finalBalance = web3.eth.getBalance(web3.eth.accounts[1])
      console.log(web3.fromWei(finalBalance).toString())

      const diff = web3.fromWei(initialBalance.minus(finalBalance))
      console.log('initialBalance - finalBalance == ' + diff)

      assert(diff > 99 && diff < 101, 'Balance after is not ~100 less than balance before.')
    })
  })
})
```

Here is the test output:

```
  test
    Contract: Contract
21267647932558650071.31300778513203191
21267647932558649871.313007785132010657
initialBalance - finalBalance == 200.000000000000021253
      1) send to deployed address
    > No events were emitted


  0 passing (2s)
  1 failing

  1) test Contract: Contract send to deployed address:
     AssertionError: Balance after is not ~100 less than balance before.
```

Comment: Appears to be a problem with testrpc: https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc/issues/122

Comment: Identified in ethereumjs-vm: https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-vm/issues/82

Comment: This bug is still there for me with testRPC 4.0.1 Has anyone found a workaround?

Comment: Test on a private chain.

Answer (score 1):

It has been fixed in latest [4.1.0 release](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc/releases/tag/v4.1.0)