# Workaround for testRPC bug where amounts spent multiple time with library calls?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, testrpc, library

Using testRPC the amount transferred is multiple times of the msg.value if a library call is involved.

There is [bug report](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc/issues/122) and it was raised
[here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7975/sendtransaction-results-in-double-send-with-arbitrary-library-call) and
[here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15549/sending-ethers-with-mocha-js-and-truffle-might-result-in-larger-sums-than-intend) as well.

It's a well documented, long standing bug in testRPC and as of testRPC v4.0.1 it's still there.

Anyone was able to come up with a workaround?

Comment: You can use a private test network, with clique if you need faster block times.

Comment: thanks. not ideal, it still slows down dev cycle too much :/

Comment: The github issue seems will be fixed in the next version of testrpc
https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc/issues/122#issuecomment-323528520

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been fixed in latest [4.1.0 release](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc/releases/tag/v4.1.0)